# Just Audio Flutter Plugin - How to convert Duration from Stream listener to Integer?

Tags: flutter, dart, duration, just-audio, flutter-streambuilder

I'm using Flutter's `Just-Audio` plugin to play an mp3 file fetched from a `streambuilder` in my app. The `streambuilder` returns the duration of the file which I need for the  `setClip` function;

```
player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: Duration(milliseconds: 10);
```

Instead of "10", the "end" point should be the file's duration minus 500ms. So I've got this stream listener in my `initState`;

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }
    Future<void> _init() async {
    await player.setUrl('https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/example.mp3');

     player.durationStream.listen((event) {
       int newevent = event.inMilliseconds;
          });
        await player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: newevent);
     }
```

But I need to convert the fetched duration to an integer in order to take off 500ms. Unfortunately the `int newevent = event.inMilliseconds;` throws the following error;

```
A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Duration?'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Duration?'.
```

I've tried this;

```
 int? newevent = event?.inMilliseconds;
```

and then;

```
 await player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: Duration(milliseconds: newevent));
```

But then I just get this redline error under `milliseconds: newevent` ;

```
 The argument type 'Duration?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
```

So how can I get my duration from my streamlistener as an integer so I can use it as the end point in `player.setClip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears because durationStream returns a [nullable](https://dart.dev/null-safety) duration, and it has to be non-nullable to be able to convert it to an integer. You can promote the duration to a non-nullable type with a null check.

Furthermore, to only run setClip after the first event, use `first` instead of `listen` and move `setClip` inside the function:

```dart
player.durationStream.first.then((event) {
  if(event != null){
    int newevent = event.inMilliseconds - 500;
    await player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: Duration(milliseconds: newevent);
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately though there was no error, when I did a hot restart it went into a loop where it endlessly tried to load. The only way to stop the loop was to remove- player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: Duration(milliseconds: newevent));

Comment: Here's another error when I tried adding async and await ; Error: Non-nullable variable 'newevent' must be assigned before it can be used.
       await player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: Duration(milliseconds: newevent - 500));

Comment: Finally able to remove errors and loop by setting int newevent=0;
int clippedevent =0; outside the initState. But although it seems work at first, both variables eventually get set back to zero somehow.

Comment: Try moving `setClip` inside the listener to make sure that newevent has a value when using it. If you only want to run `setClip` once you can use [`first`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-async/Stream/first.html) instead of `listen`.

Comment: First doesn't seem to work as a drop in replacement.  player.durationStream.first((event) - The error I get is - The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Comment: This is what worked. If you want to put it as answer, I'll choose it.   player.durationStream.first.then((event) {
      if(event != null){
        int newevent;
        newevent = event.inMilliseconds - 500;
        player.setClip(start: Duration(milliseconds: 0), end: Duration(milliseconds: newevent));
      }
    }

Comment: Sorry that it took a while to answer, glad you sorted it out. I have updated the answer